# GreaseMonkey + Ajax + Remember page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I load jquery into my greasemonkey script and when the user clicks the start button the script makes a bunch of ajax calls. I then empty body and append data. When i click on something and hit back instead of getting the page post script i lose all the data and need to run the ajax calls again (it can take seconds to run). How do i make it not lose the changes?

Comment: You've got more energy than I do, loading jQuery into Greasemonkey. Kind of like using a sledgehammer to kill an ant ... :)

Comment: nah, i copied pasted the script somewhere and jquery makes the script easier to write. especially with ajax and .get()

Comment: Actually now i see it will work with one line. provided this is in the script when it is first installed (it is downloaded once when installed and never again).
// @require        http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Will [GM_setValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Using GM_setValue("valuename",value) to save some data and GM_getValue('valuename') to get that data should achieve what you want.